# Project longitude and latitude to planar coordinates system

Tags: r, coordinate-systems, r-sf, spatstat

Disclaimer: I am currently using the `ppp` branch version of the {sf} package, because new features for converting objects between {sf} and {spatstat} are available in it (see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1233). For it to work properly, I had to manually delete the {sf} package from my hard drive and then reinstall it from Github. I am also using the development version of {spatstat} for no particular reason.

```
# install.packages("remotes")
install_github("r-spatial/sf@ppp")
install_github("spatstat/spatstat")
```

I have two geospatial objects: `area_one`, which is the union of the polygons of several counties in Texas and `vz`, which is the point locations of several stores in Texas and they are both objects of the  `sf` family. `vz` was created using longitude and latitude coordinates scraped from the internet. My goal is to create a `ppp` object with the locations in `vz` as the points and the polygon in `area_one` as the window. The issue is that I cannot find the correct coordinate reference system (CRS), for my points to lie inside the polygon. I get an error telling me that the points lie outside the window. Here are the two files to make the code below reproducible:

`area_one`: [download here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnAdvr6Ro2qsl25y4nYOBYkM3zk7?e=udla7H)

`vz`: [download here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnAdvr6Ro2qsl23KfVFVrByy1I5n?e=Gs1SPn)

```
# Load packages

library(sf) # Development version in the ppp branch
library(spatstat) # Development version in the master branch
library(tmap)
library(here)

# Read the geospatial data (CRS = 4326)

area_one <- st_read(dsn = here("area_one/area_one.shp"), layer = "area_one")
vz <- st_read(dsn = here("vz/vz.shp"), layer = "vz")

# Plot a quick map

tm_shape(area_one) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_shape(vz) +
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = 0.1)
```

[image]

```
# Create a planar point pattern

vz_lonlat <- st_coordinates(vz)
area_one_flat <- st_transform(area_one, crs = 6345)

p <- ppp(x = vz_lonlat[, "X"], y = vz_lonlat[, "Y"], window = as.owin(area_one_flat)) # Note that the reason why this line of code does not throw an error (especially despite the window argument being an sf object) is because of the version of the {sf} package I am using

Warning message:
49 points were rejected as lying outside the specified window 

plot(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Why haven't you also transformed `vz` to the coordinate system you've transformed `area_one_flat` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @spacedman points out you should first transform `vz` to the same coordinate system as the observation region. I guess you could do something like (untested):

```
vz_flat <- st_coordinates(st_transform(vz, crs = 6345))
area_one_flat <- st_transform(area_one, crs = 6345)
p <- ppp(x = vz_flat[, "X"], y = vz_flat[, "Y"], window = as.owin(area_one_flat))
```